# pixel.quantserve.com - what's it about, and should I block it?

Tags: discussion, advertising, cookies

I was just checking what items were downloaded by the SO pages, and I saw pixel.quantserve.com popping up. My first instinct was to block it using Adblock Plus, but I'd like to know what it's for.

Any reason *not* to block "http://*.quantserve.com/" ??

Comment: actually, this never finished downloading for me and the page just remains with a permanent download status bar.

Comment: That freaking thing is annoying because it apparently never completes loading.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Quantserve is like Google Analytics, but totally public.

(this is important to attract advertisers, as they see your public validated traffic rank and have some idea of the type and number of visitors they might be advertising to)

http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com

I wish Google Analytics offered a world-public view into your web stats and we wouldn't need Quantserve..

EDIT: sometime in the last ~5 years, this has been moved to private data only.

Comment: Is there a link to seeing the public SO traffic rank? Just curious...

Comment: Doesn't GA have an API for this?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood quantserve is currently crippling all StackExchange sites for me - every page takes 20+ seconds to load as it hangs on edge.quantserve.com :(

Comment: This link doesn't seem to work currently

Comment: They're not *private* per se; you just need to have a registered account in order to view them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313679/377214

Answer (score 5):

[Noscript](http://noscript.net/) blocks it as a matter of course, so I guess you are losing quite a bit of data. Certainly more than a site with 'average' users!

Comment: This is true.  I have Noscript set to block all quantserve.com traffic.