# Am I allowed to include Stack Exchange resources (images, css) with a plugin for offline use?

Tags: support, api, copyright

I'm working on a plugin that adds some degree of offline functionality to Stack Exchange. It needs to be able to render pages without internet access.

I am going to bundle jQuery and WMD/PageDown with my plugin because their licenses allow me to, but I don't think I can legally include Stack Exchange's other resources without permissions. I see three possibilities:

1. **Don't use** Stack Exchange's resources while offline. Write write my own CSS and JavaScript to achieve a subset of Stack Exchange's functionality.
2. **Cache** Stack Exchange's resources when online, and serve them from this cache when offline. This may result in some resources being unavailable when offline, if they weren't cached first.
3. **Include** Stack Exchange's resources with my plugin. Use the current copies while online, but fall back to the packaged copies when offline.

My impression is that #2 would be okay without permission, but that #3 would not be. I'd like to be able to bundle everything if I could. The resources would only be used to recreate Stack Overflow pages while offline, they wouldn't be used for any other purpose.

What I am allowed to do?

---

#### See Also

- [Add an HTML5 offline fallback page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101164/add-an-html5-offline-fallback-page)

Comment: Possibly related: [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance). It doesn't cover scripts, but does cover look & feel and logos and such. You might have to get explicit written permission to use stuff from SE or design your own UI.

Comment: I think #2 is your safest bet. IANAL, YMMV, yadda yadda

Answer (score 4):

I recommend #2 since it's the most standard pattern, the one all web browsers use.