# What happened to the public Quantcast statistics?

Tags: discussion, statistics, quantcast

There used to be publicly accessibly Quantcast statistics available for each site, such as [this one](https://www.quantcast.com/christianity.stackexchange.com/geo/countries). These links now require you to log in.

What happened to these statistics, and are there any alternatives?

Comment: You're sure that this isn't an issue with Quantcast, right?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I've tried to open past links multiple times across many weeks, it's not a temporary issue. I expect the stats have been locked down, or perhaps SE no longer is using Quantcast.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog afaik, you can select to make private some information. I will check now on my account and see if it's right. And... I can see them if I'm logged it, if I'm anonymous user I can't.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog well, it was with Quantcast

Answer (score 5):

There's is a configuration under /user/config?s=propertyid (?) for Quancast, where you can select if there's public access to that property stats, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have all the values as public, yet I'm asked for my account if I try on a private window for any property, mine included. Meanwhile I can see Stack Exchange when I'm logged in, but not as a anonymous user.

Seems that the onus is on Quancast, that for some motive, changed the behavior of the public statistic:

> Yes, **we made a move a few months ago so all public profiles are now behind a login wall**. Users must be logged in to look at Quantcast profiles.
>
> If you have selected reports to be public, all logged in users can view them.
> Reports that are set to private can only be viewed by the admin (you) and any users you give authorized access to. Those users must be logged in as well to view your profile.

Comment: Does this mean the SE stats are visible if we sign up for a Quantcast account? Are Quantcast accounts free?

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, and also yes. I'm not sure if you have to set up a property.